# google drive api v2 php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Не работает скачивание файлов. [Вот функция из документации](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-downloads).

Пишет: `Class 'Google_Http_Request' not found`, 
[здесь](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md) написано, что `Removed Google_Http_Request`.

Если использовать подобие, изменив запрос на GET и ссылку подставить, как описано в последней ссылке выше

```
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', $url);
$response = $httpClient->send($request);
```

То пишет

```
Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface GuzzleHttp\Message\RequestInterface, instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request given, called in \file.php on line 37 and defined in \vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php on line 158
```

Существует ли решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть кому то пригодится, вот решение проблемы:

```
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$response = $httpClient->get($url);
echo $response->getBody();
```